# How to graph a color function relationship

Tags: color, graphs

I am looking for LaTeX code for coloring a rectangle based on a formula that gives the color at `$(x,y)$` location via a formula `$z=f(x,y)$`, where `$z$` is the wavelength  and we want a spot of color `$z$` to show at `$(x,y)$`.

Explanation:

In relativity color of light is affected by the speed of observer, source, reflector, etc. For example for normal reflection one may have a relationship as  `$\lambda_r=\frac{1-\beta}{1+\beta}} \lmbda_i$`  where `$\lambda_i$` is the incident wavelength, $\lambda_r$ is the reflected wavelength, and `$\beta$` is some fractional speed in the `$(-1,1)$` range. Here the question is how to graph this formula with colors.

For example the horizontal axis can show the the visible portion of light spectrum for `$\lambda_i$`, the vertical axis can show `$\beta$`, and each point at coordinate  `$(\lambda_i,\beta)$` can be colored with the color of `$\lambda_r$` (with some provision made for infra-red or ultraviolet regions).

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear at the moment (for me at least, I know very little about physics). Could you provide a screenshot of the type of plot you are looking for? It would also help to clarify the question if you can provide a minimal document in LaTeX that shows the kind of syntax that you want to use in terms of a macro call with arguments, maybe other elements in the code that are fixed or can be set separately, etc, so that people that are interested in answering can basically fill in your example with the actual code.

Comment: Unrelated: in questions here on the site you cannot use LaTeX notation, because the site is _about_ LaTeX, so `$\beta$` shows up as `$\beta$` in your question text and not as β.

Comment: @Marijn  Figure 1 or 8 in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Doppler_effect) is an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `xcolor` package provides a `wave` model which allows you to specify the color based on the wavelength.  You need to complete `\ComputeColor` for your purposes to return a value in the range [363,..,814] based on the x and y coordinate. With my version of `\ComputeColor` the MWE below yields:

[image]

#### Code:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*{\DeltaX}{0.01}%
\newcommand*{\DeltaY}{0.01}%
\newcommand*{\XMin}{1}%
\newcommand*{\XMax}{3}%
\newcommand*{\YMin}{0}%
\newcommand*{\YMax}{1}%

\makeatletter
\pgfmathsetmacro{\XFirstStep}{\XMin+\DeltaX}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\YFirstStep}{\YMin+\DeltaY}%
\def\@MinWavelength{363}%  lambda in nm units
\def\@MaxWavelength{814}%
\def\XWeight{0.3}%
\def\YWeight{0.2}%
\newcommand{\ComputeColor}[3]{%
    %% #1 = macro to contain color specification
    %% #2 = x coordinate
    %% #3 = y coordinate
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro#1{%
         (\@MaxWavelength-\@MinWavelength)
        *(
            \XWeight*(#2-\XMin)/(\XMax-\XMin)
           +\YWeight*(#3-\YMin)/(\YMax-\YMin)
         )
        +\@MinWavelength
    }%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    %\draw [gray] (\XMin,\YMin) rectangle (\XMax, \YMax);
    \foreach \x in {\XMin, \XFirstStep, ..., \XMax} {
        \foreach \y in {\YMin, \YFirstStep, ..., \YMax} {
            \ComputeColor{\CurrentColor}{\x}{\y}%
            %\typeout{\x,\y: \color=\CurrentColor}% 
            \definecolor{MyColor}{wave}{\CurrentColor}
            \fill [MyColor] (\x+0.5*\DeltaX,\y+0.5*\DeltaY) circle (\DeltaX);
        }%
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```